# What is this White Horse a reference to?

Tags: reference, twin-peaks, unbreakable-kimmy-schmidt

In episode 9 of *Unbreakable Kimmy Schmidt*, at the end, the stepfather, who seems to be coming down after doing Heroin, sees a White Horse in the restaurant. What is this a reference to?

[image: The White Horse]

There is a thread on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/KimmySchmidt/comments/2y7s09/pop_culture_in_unbreakable_kimmy_schmidt/cp9v6yl) that reckons this is a reference to *Twin Peaks*.

[image: The White Horse in Twin Peaks]

So the question is: is this a direct homage to *Twin Peaks* or is it a reference to another famous scene?

Comment: I thought the white horse in that twin peaks scene was a reference to something else. It doesn't really add anything to the plot.

Comment: Heroin is often referred to as "horse."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually a homage to the song "[White Horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Horse_(Laid_Back_song))" by Laid Back. I don't know if that song was played in *Twin Peaks*, but I do know that the words "white horse" were in reference to heroin, which Kimmy's dad was high on, and the song also says "white pony" in reference to cocaine. I remember this song from the 80s, and Kimmy was stuck in that time slot, which makes sense with the horse and her dad.

Comment: interesting, I knew the herion reference but not the song reference

Comment: Good catch.  Heroin is often referred to as "H" or "Horse".